# In an html page,how to display the first page of a pdf document as the icon?

Tags: html, image, pdf

I have used the following code to display a list of PDF files in an HTML page. I want to display the first page of every PDF file as the image icon for them. I am not using any servers as of now. Please guide me on this.
Code goes here:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link type="text/css" href="cssjquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Unit 3, ADS</title>
<style type="text/css">
.imagewrap {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

</style>


<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsjquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsjquery/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('a.btn').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    pdfID = $(this).closest('.imagewrap')[0].id;
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
  alert('Deleting '+pdfID+'');
   $(this).closest('.imagewrap')
        .fadeTo(300,0,function(){
            $(this)
                .animate({width:0},200,function(){
                    $(this)
                        .remove();
                });
        });   
});
}); 


</script>
</head>
<body>


    <h1>PDF Files</h1>
<br><br>
    <div class="imagewrap" id="pdf1">
        <a href="something1.pdf"><img src="pdf icon.jpg" width="100" height="100" border="0"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn" href="#"><i class=" icon-remove-sign" ></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="imagewrap" id="pdf2">
        <a href="something2.pdf"><img src="pdf icon.jpg" width="100" height="100" border="0"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn" href="#"><i class=" icon-remove-sign" ></i></a>
    </div>
<div class="imagewrap" id="pdf3">
        <a href="something3.pdf"><img src="pdf icon.jpg" width="100" height="100" border="0"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn" href="#"><i class=" icon-remove-sign" ></i></a>
    </div>

</body>
```

P.S. : I have added imagewrap class to each div here because I was not able to add the remove icon to every pdf icon image otherwise.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781793/how-to-display-the-first-page-of-a-pdf-file-as-icon-when-the-pdfs-are-added-in-a

Answer (score 1):

A quick search for "pdf thumbnail service" revealed a couple of services. Most of them are freemium (free up to a number of hits per month).

I tried a few with the following URL (PDF reference):
http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf

- bluga.net: Was still crunching after minutes
- shrinktheweb.com: Returned the first page nicely in a second
- websnapr.com: Displayed broken image in a second
- thumbalizr.com: Returned 'picture failed' after 13 seconds

Beased on this quick experiment I would take a closer look at shrinktheweb.com (not affiliated).

Comment: I am not able to access shrinktheweb.com since that category is blocked in my system. I even tried websnapr.com but no image was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use images for the preview, you have to render every .pdf file. 
Simplest way would be an IFrame, but you can find more solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html).

But keep in mind that every .pdf you put in an IFrame will be loaded completely und if you have a list of several .pdf's it could make your page quite slow.